# read XML file to create a 3D model

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

I have to load the Data from XML (custom but its based on XML file format (URF-8)) and use them to create model in Unity. I used XmlSerializer class, custom creation and tried all XML helps in forums, etc..
I debugged everything (step by step) and everything works fine but after that i always have problem with container. (i have error with reading)
Please, if you have any experince with this, can you tell me what method can be useful for this? ty

[XML struct file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMVb1.png)

here is my try for XMLserializer: (some discriptions of tags XML are commented (tried everything :D)

```
//load.cs - creating a container
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Load
{
    //[XmlAttribute("block type")]
    public float x_position;
    public float y_position;
    public float z_position;
}

//[XmlRoot("model version")]
public class Container
{
    //[XmlArrayItem("block type")]
    public List<Load> Load_container = new List<Load>();
}

//loadFile is main program.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;


public class LoadFile: MonoBehaviour
{
    public string path;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Container));
        var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        var container_load = serializer.Deserialize(stream) as Container;
        stream.Close();

        //Debug.Log();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
    [XmlRoot("model")]
    public class Model
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string version { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("block")]
        List<Block> block { get; set; }
    }
    public class Block
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string type { get; set; }
        public float x_position { get; set; }
        public float y_position { get; set; }
        public float z_position { get; set; }
    }
```